# How to implement singleton in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

In kornshell, `basename $0` gives me the name of the current script.

How would I exploit $$ or $PPID to implement the singleton pattern of only having one script named `basename $0` executed on this server by any user?

```
ps -ef|grep `basename $0`
```

This will show me all processes which are running that have the name of the currently running script.

I need a script which can abort when a thread which is not $$ is running the script named `basename $0`.

Comment: It seems to me that you've got a problem, and you've chosen a solution to that problem far too early. What problem are you *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: `ps` is unsuited for this role: it doesn't provide atomicity or concurrency guarantees; its result isn't guaranteed to represent any particular point in time. I find myself in rather overwhelming agreement with Philip.

Comment: @Goahnary You may find this of interest, by the way, if your issue is caused by the instance of your script *reading* your counter overlapping with another instance of the script *writing* the counter. Note that `echo foo > bar` is not atomic -- it first truncates `bar` to be an empty file *before* writing `foo` into it; for your numeric counter, this would look like resetting back to 0, until/unless you implement a mutex to ensure that only one job runs at a time. (If the server recently started taking longer to respond, that would explain why you only started seeing bugs recently).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide a race-free mutex, `flock` is your friend. If you aren't on Linux -- where it's [provided by util-linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) -- a [portable version](https://github.com/discoteq/flock) is available.

If you truly want it to apply to the entire system -- crossing user accounts -- you'll need a directory for your locks to live where all users can create files, and you'll need to ensure that all users can write to your lockfiles.

Assuming you have the `flock` utility, each program which wants to participate in this protocol can behave as follows:

```
#!/bin/ksh

umask 000                  # allow all users to access the file we're about to create
exec 9>"/tmp/${0##*/}.lck" # open lockfile on FD 9, based on basename of argv[0]
umask 022                  # move back to more restrictive file permissions
flock -x -n 9 || exit      # grab that lock, or exit the script early

# continue
```

One key note: **Do not** try to delete lockfiles when your script exits. If you're in a condition where someone else is actively trying to grab a lock, they'll already have a file descriptor on that existing file; if you delete the file while they have a handle on it, you just ensured a race wherein that program can think it holds the lock while someone else creates a new file under the same name and locks it.

Comment: There is no atomicity between your commands and so is no guarantee. I don't believe what is being asked is actually possible the way he wants it to be.

Comment: @bodangly, the key thing here is that as soon as the flock executable invokes the `flock` syscall, no other `flock(LOCK_EX)` on a different file descriptor for the same inode will succeed until that fd is closed or unlocked with `flock(LOCK_UN)`. Because the shell script holds that file descriptor open for the rest of its execution, that means nothing else can get past the `flock -x -n 9` line until that script holding the lock, and every executable it ran which inherited a copy of its FD table, exits.

Comment: @bodangly, ...can you explain to me your objection in the light of the plain text of http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock ?

Comment: Because anyone with sufficient privileges can circumvent your lockfiles. Your solution will work in the general case, but is mot a guarantee the way a singleton is.

Comment: @bodangly, (...aside: I was mentor for a HackIllinois project to try to add support for correctly modeling the flock syscall's behavior to `sysdig`. The result of that effort was really proof-of-concept level, but I came out of it knowing much more about how the kernel implements the corner cases around that syscall than I ever wanted to before).

Comment: @bodangly, oh, yeah, absolutely they can be circumvented. It's an advisory, participatory protocol by nature. But... well, any "singleton" measure can be circumvented by that measure, by using a different process image, or a different Java classloader to hold a distinct copy of your object, or whatever other hackery you want. Any piece of code that's written in such a way as to enforce a singleton is inherently voluntarily participate in a protocol for the purpose.

Comment: @bodangly, ...and, well, if you wanted to add an enforcement measure, that *is* possible. If piece-of-software-X wants to check whether your FD 9 is really on the inode referred to by `/tmp/${0##*/}.lck` and whether you really do hold a lock on it, that's a thing that **can** be enforced.

Comment: True, but it is fairly trivial in this case. Furthermore, you can create the lockfile but someone else can destroy it before you get a chance to call flock. If you want an atomic check and set, mkdir is your best bet, but it is also easy to circumvent of course.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think I accept your premise that difficulty of circumvention is a necessary property of a singleton.

Comment: @bodangly, ...and re: "someone else can destroy it", not if you do your file permissions right. If you have `+t`, multiple users can create files in a directory, but only the owner of an individual file or root can destroy it. You'll note I suggested using `/tmp`, where this is true by default.

Comment: Fair enough, but I have seen enough race conditions in lockfiles implemented in shell scripts to experience forst hand the problems that arise with the lack of atomicity on calling flock after a file has been created. This is why I would recommend mkdir instead as the check and set becomes atomic.

Comment: @bodangly, ...yes, there are idiots who delete lockfiles, and break their guarantees in that way, or who exec programs that close all FDs other than stdin/stdout/stderr (and, by failing to keep the parent shell open until that program exits, fail to maintain the lockfile handle through end of execution). The `mkdir` approach buys you better behavior in those two scenarios -- and support for network filesystems without `flock(2)` support -- but what it loses you is automatic lock release on unclean exit, which is a property I'm unwilling to compromise on.

Comment: @bodangly, ...I've seen, firsthand, too much downtime caused by lockfiles left over after unclean restarts (and lost too much hair to nonreproducible issues that may well have been PID collisions w/ the pidfile approach) to consider anything else reasonable. I suppose we're each the set of our experiences.