# Run shell script exactly once with cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a cron job that calls a script that checks for updates once every hour. If there are updates, it will call `update.sh`, which in turn calls `commands.sh`. I would like each "new" `commands.sh` to be run exactly once.

I was thinking of writing to a file each time I run `commands.sh` with some unique ID of that file. Before running `commands.sh`, I check if the file contains the ID of `commands.sh`. If so, don't run it.

Edit - more detail:

cronjob:

- fetch from git repo, pull and merge if any changes
- Run `update.sh`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  ./commands.sh
  ```

I want `./commands.sh` to run just once, because next hour, the cron will run again, pull from git, and run `update.sh` again. Is there some way for each unique `./commands.sh` to run just once?

After writing that out, maybe the best way is just to only run `update.sh` if there was a change from the git repo?

This seems like overkill and hard to maintain. Is there a simpler way to write a bash script that only runs one time?

Comment: Is your problem that a former instance of `commands.sh` might still be running when the next update is due? Or who else is invoking the second instance?

Comment: From `update.sh`, is `mv commands.sh commands.sh-done-(timestamp)` a possibility?

Comment: Are you trying to use `cron` as if it were a process supervision system (responsible for keeping a daemon running, restarting it if it exits, but never starting more than one instance)? Because the best-practice answer there is "don't" -- there are **real** process supervision services built for the purpose, and they'll do a better job.

Comment: ...and similarly, if your goal is to run a command every time there's content pushed to `git`... well, there are `git`-specific ways to do that that don't have all the lag and general-purpose fail of relying on `cron`.

Comment: I would love to see these alternatives you're talking about. I was using cron exactly as you described

Comment: @Nick, ...so, what's your operating system? If it uses systemd or upstart, or... err, Apple's process supervision system, the name of which I'm forgetting [edit: Apple's is `launchd`], then you've got something already installed for the purpose. If you're answering my first comment, about running a service and keeping it up, as opposed to the second (best practices for a server-side trigger on every `git push`).

Comment: It's a raspberry pi (Raspbian). In the future, it might be something even less complicated (beaglebone, etc).

Comment: For a tiny embedded system, `runit` is your best bet; its authors make some effort to be sure that it works with tiny `libc`s (much smaller than glibc). See http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2012/12/29/process-supervision-solved-problem/ (first Google link, but on browsing, I like what it has to say).

Comment: Why wouldn't you just remove (delete) the ./commands.sh file from the system right after it's done. it would never run again :)

Comment: Holy crap you may be on to something. Seriously, I thought this wouldn't work because git would get angry that I've removed a file and wouldn't let me pull, but it's totally fine.

Comment: Your question says "If there are updates it will call `update.sh` which will call `commands.sh`. So if there are no updates, it won't call `update.sh`, and it won't call `commands.sh`. Why isn't that adequate?

Comment: There are updates which may not involve commands.sh. As in, a file could get updated but commands.sh is still old, and it will rerun it. However, I've realized that I can do it just like you said: only really run updates.sh if there are updates to commands.sh, or something

Comment: Easy to always `touch stampfile`, and look at `[ commands.sh -nt stampfile ]` to see who's changed. Doesn't solve your locking needs, and I don't consider your accepted answer's locking suggestion adequate, but there are plenty of other questions and answers on how to do that reliably and robustly; ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401405/how-to-implement-singleton-in-shell-script/37401629#37401629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of the `commands.sh` script do this:

```
if [ -f stampfile ]; then
    exit
if
touch stampfile
```

This checks for a file called `stampfile` (specify a path to anywhere convenient where this may be stored).  If it's there, just `exit`.  If it's not there create it with `touch`.

Then let the script do its thing.

*A slight digression:* This can also be used to avoid having two instances of a script running at the same time. The script would then `rm -f stampfile` at the end of its run.

In this case, if the script is killed, the `stampfile` will be "stale" (stamp present but script not alive). To detect a stale `stampfile`, put the PID of the script into it instead of touching it.

To check if there's another instance running, and managing the stampfile:

```
if [ -f stampfile ]; then
    if kill -0 $(<stampfile) 2>/dev/null; then
        exit
    else
        rm -f stampfile    # stale
    fi
fi
echo $$ >stampfile

# rest of script

rm -f stampfile
```

User @CharlesDuffy points out that this way of managing the `stampfile` may be prone to PID reuse issues, i.e. that the PID in a stale `stampfile` might be that of a running process that has nothing to do with any of this. There is apparently [a Linux utility called `flock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) that allows you to do this in a more robust way.

Comment: PID-based lock detection is very much not ideal -- PIDs are by no means guaranteed unique. Consider `flock`-based locking instead, which will also automatically clear itself on process death, including by reboot or other hard-shutdown scenarios.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `flock` is not available on my systems (OpenBSD and Mac OS X), so I can't test it. Sorry. I do have `shlock` on the Mac though, but not on OpenBSD. Any portable alternatives?

Comment: See https://github.com/discoteq/flock for an implementation not tied to `util-linux`. I also vaguely remember there being a `lockfile` command available that could use either `flock()` or `fcntl(LOCK_*)` back in days of yore (portable to Solaris, Linux, and I'm-not-sure-what-else), but don't know how actively maintained it is of late.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I might, but as this is not the main issue in the question, I won't be updating the answer. I'll make a note in there though.